# cakephp belongsTo custom condition not working

Tags: cakephp

```
// in Person
public $hasMany = array(
'PersonRecommendation' => array(
    'className' => 'PersonRecommendation',
    'foreignKey' => false,
    'dependent' => true,
),
)

// in PersonRecommendation
public $belongsTo = array(
'Person' => array(
    'className' => 'Person',
    'foreignKey' => false,
    'conditions' => array('Person.email = PersonRecommendation.email'),
),
);
```

When I query these out with find() the Person returns ALL recommendations. Not just those associated by email. I've tried a variety of different things, and I'm stumped. Can someone help?

Using cake 2.4.5.

Comment: Put conditions on the $hasMany relation (just like you did for the PersonRecommendation's belongsTo relation)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the Person model

```
public $hasMany = array(
   'PersonRecommendation' => array(
       'className' => 'PersonRecommendation',
       'foreignKey' => false,
       'dependent' => true,
       'conditions' => array('Person.email = PersonRecommendation.email')
    )
)
```

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr - What do you need explained - the `hasMany` configuration? Why would this throw a database error? You need to be more specific if you want me to explain this solution to you (which BTW- we don't know if this solution worked for the OP.)

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
'conditions' => array($Person->email => $PersonRecommendation->email)
```